# AWS MySQL backup cron not running

Tags: cron

I have this cron:

```
00 0 * * * root /home/bitnami/backup.sh > /home/bitnami/backup.log
```

The Backup script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
file=$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql
mysqldump \
  --host localhost \
  --port 3306 \
  -u user \
  --password="123" \
  bitnami > ${file}
if [ "${?}" -eq 0 ]; then
  gzip ${file}
  aws --region us-west-2 s3 cp ${file}.gz s3://backups/fc-wiki/
  rm ${file}.gz
else
  echo "Error backing up mysql"
  exit 255
fi
```

Which works fine when executing it by hand (`sudo .\backup.sh`)

When the crontab runs it only logs the following error in backup.log:
`Error backing up mysql`

Is there a problem how I'm setting up the cron tab with the piping to log perhaps? Even without the piping it doesn't work.

Comment: Check your syslog for any errors.

Comment: ***cron runs your command in a restricted environment.**
What environment variables are available is likely to be very limited. Typically, you'll only get a few variables defined, such as `$LOGNAME` `$HOME,` and `$PATH`.

Of particular note is the PATH is restricted to `/bin:/usr/bin`. The vast majority of "my cron script doesn't work" problems are caused by this restrictive path"*